# Openssl Custom Extension

Tags: command-line-interface, openssl, x509

I know how to create x509 certificates with the openssl command line. But now I want to create one with a custom extension. How can I do this with openssl command line?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example for adding a set of S/MIME client capability extensions when signing an S/MIME user cert, taken from [an example on the OpenSSL mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg58525.html):

```
[my_cert_extensions]
basicConstraints         = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                 = critical, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
SMIME-CAPS               = ASN1:SEQUENCE:smime_seq
subjectKeyIdentifier     = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier   = keyid,issuer

[ smime_seq ]
SMIMECapability.0 = SEQWRAP,OID:sha1
SMIMECapability.1 = SEQWRAP,OID:sha256
SMIMECapability.2 = SEQWRAP,OID:sha1WithRSA
SMIMECapability.3 = SEQWRAP,OID:aes-256-ecb
SMIMECapability.4 = SEQWRAP,OID:aes-256-cbc
SMIMECapability.5 = SEQWRAP,OID:aes-256-ofb
SMIMECapability.6 = SEQWRAP,OID:aes-128-ecb
SMIMECapability.7 = SEQWRAP,OID:aes-128-cbc
SMIMECapability.8 = SEQWRAP,OID:aes-128-ecb
SMIMECapability.9 = SEQUENCE:rsa_enc

[ rsa_enc ]
capabilityID = OID:rsaEncryption
parameter = NULL
```

This is activated by, amongst other ways, using `openssl` command-line option `-extensions my_cert_extensions`.

There are two more pieces to the puzzle:

- more details on how extension data can be constructed is in the OpenSSL API documentation [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ASN1_generate_nconf.html), but you need to know a little about [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) and [OIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier) to make sense of that.
- if your extension really is custom then you probably should [apply](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) to IANA for a [Private Enterprise Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_enterprise_number) (this is a must if your extensions may be seen in the wild)

If you wish to add text using an *existing* extension it's usually a little easier, if you have:

```
[ CA_default ]
...
x509_extensions = usr_cert

[ usr_cert ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
...
nsComment = "This is my comment"
```

`CA_default` is used during the normal CA signing, if you can use a pre-defined extension then all you have to do is add it to the `usr_cert` section, no extra command line options required. (`nsComment` is technically deprecated, but it still works, it's a simple example and is easily viewable within certificate properties in common browsers).

See the [`x509v3_config` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html) which explains extensions basics, and the OpenSSL source [crypto/objects/objects.txt](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=crypto/objects/objects.txt;h=fc32606deb194af450da5400081cdd22ba352025;hb=df4439186fb70ce72668d472943dbcd057df8f30) for the somewhat cryptic details (this file is processed and used to generate code).

An OID is typically associated with a discrete concept, like a *noun*, a *verb*, an *attribute* or even something less tangible (like UUIDs, but hierarchical). [nsComment](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.16.840.1.113730.1.13.html) has a defined meaning (free-form text comments inside certificates), others like [`keyUsage`](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.15.html) have stricter semantics.

Within OpenSSL the name "nsComment" is mapped to OID 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13, as set in `objects.txt`.
Every extension in an X.509v3 certificate has an OID, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299201/asn-1-octet-strings .

If there is no suitable extension in OpenSSL (see [RFC 5280 §4.2 Certificate Extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2)), you may be able to find one and add it (see the "Arbitrary Extensions" section in the `x509v3_config` man page linked above). Otherwise you will need to define OIDs for your own purposes.

Comment: I just need to add a couple of strings in a custom extension. Do I need ASN1 & OIDs?

Comment: @user93353 If you're trying to add an extension defined elsewhere (say in an RFC) but unsupported by OpenSSL, the OIDs will be specified with the extension spec. If _you_ are the one defining the extension, then yes, you will need your own OID prefix. IANA's PEN registration (which I did last year) is quite painless, but there is about a 6-week lead time.

Comment: Man page above has moved to: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/x509v3_config.html

Answer (score 3):

Add the custom extension to either a custom openssl.cnf configuration file or a specific extensions file and reference that on your commandline e.g.

```
openssl ca -config ./my-openssl.cnf -extensions ./my-openssl-extensions.cnf <options>
```

From the manual page:

> **-extensions section**
>    the section of the configuration file containing certificate
>    extensions to be added when a certificate is issued (defaults to
>    x509_extensions unless the -extfile option is used). If no
>    extension section is present then, a V1 certificate is created. If
>    the extension section is present (even if it is empty), then a V3
>    certificate is created. See the `x509v3_config(5)` manual page for
>    details of the extension section format.

Comment: As correctly stated in your quote but not your example, `-extensions x` specifies a _section_ name and `-extfile y` specifies the file name if different