# error when trying to add custom extensions to X509 certificates using openSSL

Tags: openssl, self-signed-certificate, x509

I am trying to add custom extensions to my self-signed certificate.
I tried the following

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -extfile myconfig.cnf -extensions v3_req
```

Error is

`unknown option -extfile`

myconfig.cnf

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req

[v3_req]
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8=ASN1:UTF8String:Something
```

when I remove `-extfile myconfig.cnf -extensions v3_req`, I see cert.pem created successfully.

I do see -extfile is not a valid option. However, I see other posts suggesting the same
[Openssl Custom Extension](https://serverfault.com/questions/581023/openssl-custom-extension)

*EDIT*

I used `-config` instead of `-extfile` but I get the following error

```
unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config
problems making Certificate Request
4646921836:error:0EFFF06C:configuration file routines:CRYPTO_internal:no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/conf/conf_lib.c:322:group=req name=distinguished_name
```

Comment: The other Q you link is about the openssl `ca` subcommand, not the `req` subcommand. These are different, althouth they both use the same syntax in the config file/section once that is determined.

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration file contains two small errors:

1. When called with `-x509` **req** does not look for the `req_extensions`, but the `x509_extensions` section,
2. Your configuration file does not contain a **distinguished name** attribute, which is the only certificate attribute without a default value.

Therefore a minimal configuration file would look like this:

```
[ req ]
distinguished_name = dn
x509_extensions = extensions
prompt = no

[ extensions ]
1.2.3.4 = ASN1:UTF8String:Something

[ dn ]
0.DC = com
1.DC = example
commonName = example.com
```

The `prompt` option disables prompting for the distinguished name RDNs. You can generate your certificate with:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem\
-days 365 -config myconfig.cnf
```

A more complete example should, of course, include some standard extensions in the `[ extensions ]` section, which you can find in the standard OpenSSL config:

```
# PKIX recommendation.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-config` option to specify the configuration, instead of `-extfile`. In your case, this file should have a `[v3_req]` section.

For details see [openssl req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-req.html) man page.